# Expanding information from one row to all similarly grouped rows in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am not sure of the logic required to accomplish this, but I want to take a table like this...

```
+----+------+
| Id | Type |
+----+------+
| 10 | A    |
| 10 | B    |
| 10 | C    |
| 20 | A    |
| 20 | C    |
+----+------+
```

...and end up with a table like this...

```
+----+------+---+---+---+
| Id | Type | A | B | C |
+----+------+---+---+---+
| 10 | A    | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | B    | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | C    | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 20 | A    | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 20 | C    | 1 | 0 | 1 |
+----+------+---+---+---+
```

...where each `Id` will have new columns created to consolidate information about `Type` into every row of that `Id`. Since 10 has a row of types A, B, and C, then all rows that have an ID of 10 should have a 1/true in the new columns `A`, `B` and `C`.

I know how to do this on a per-row basis, but can't wrap my head around how to consolidate the information from multiple rows into each row of the same ID.

Comment: In B column on what basis you are getting 0's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below logic- [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d9fe3f37e7834ffdbaf1ee605e6c1222)

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Type) FROM your_table B WHERE B.ID = A.Id and B.Type = 'A') A,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Type) FROM your_table C WHERE C.ID = A.Id and C.Type = 'B') B,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Type) FROM your_table D WHERE D.ID = A.Id and D.Type = 'C') C
FROM your_table A
```

And just another option- [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e7e68fccadefb59ca7e25365f0b1d94b)

```
SELECT *,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type= 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) A,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type= 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) B,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type= 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) C
FROM your_table
```